# store png including email and name from ios app and include bigger picture

Tags: ios, database, email, png

So I made a simple drawing app. The idea is that every drawing will be stored in a database with the name of the user and his/her email address. From the database, the drawing will be shown online on a website and the drawing must be send to the email address from the user. Only, the drawing must be placed into a bigger drawing/picture/background/template. The user must receive a default picture, with there drawing in it.

I only have the drawing app for now... How do i begin to store etc.?
Also, is it even possible to store a transparant png file from ios?

Thanks!

Comment: Look into a [backend service](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20482/how-to-choose-the-best-backend-provider-for-your-ios-app-parse-vs-stackmob-vs-appcelerator-cloud-and-more). I prefer parse.com.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know them. How easy. :-)